# Update a 3d numpy array at given indices in a vectorized way using a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to place data in a 3d numpy array from a 2d array using the following code:

```
data = # some data has shape for eg: (300, 400)
di = # axis 0 indices has same shape as data (300, 400)
dj = # axis 1 indices has same shape as data (300, 400)
dz = # axis 2 indices has same shape as data (300, 400)
output = # output has shape (80, 90, 5)
for idx in range(data.size):
    data_pt = data.flat[idx]
    di_idx = di.flat[idx]
    dj_idx = dj.flat[idx]
    dz_idx = dz.flat[idx]
    output[di_idx, dj_idx, dz_idx] = data_pt
```

But this code becomes very slow for large `data` numpy arrays.
I tried to vectorize using:

```
indices = np.stack([di, dj, dz])
output[indices] += data
```

But I get out-of-bounds error:
IndexError: index 80 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 80

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I am able to speed up the code by using `numba.jit(nopython=True)` but I want to understand how to do this myself.

Comment: multidimensional indices have to be a tuple, one array for each dimension.  A smaller concrete example might be needed.  If there are duplicates, look at `np.add.at`

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I have found the proper way. this worked for me:
```i_idxes = di.reshape(-1).astype(numpy.int)
j_idxes = dj.reshape(-1).astype(numpy.int)
z_idxes = dz.reshape(-1).astype(numpy.int)
output[i_idxes, j_idxes, z_idxes] += data.reshape(-1)```